# Errors on end game on score

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

OK I"ve managed to fix most of the error, the main remaining ones are when I try to make the game end when it hits 50... This is now the error I get and when I go into the next level the ship disappears, but the game plays with an invisible ship....

> ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
>       at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
>       at SpaceRocks_v008/newShip()[/Users/Jess/Documents/UNI/INFT6303_game_design/Ass_3/Flash_V2/SpaceRocks_v008.as:168]
>       at SpaceRocks_v008/startSpaceRocks_v008()[/Users/Jess/Documents/UNI/INFT6303_game_design/Ass_3/Flash_V2/SpaceRocks_v008.as:84]
>       at SpaceRocks_v008/frame2()
>   Cannot display source code at this location.

```
 package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.geom.Point;

public class SpaceRocks_v008 extends MovieClip {
    static const shipRotationSpeed:Number = .1;
    static const rockSpeedStart:Number = .03;
    static const rockSpeedIncrease:Number = .02;
    static const missileSpeed:Number = .2;
    static const thrustPower:Number = .15;
    static const shipRadius:Number = 20;
    static const startingShips:uint = 3;

    // game objects
    private var ship:Ship;
    private var rocks:Array;
    private var missiles:Array;

    // animation timer
    private var lastTime:uint;

    // arrow keys
    private var rightArrow:Boolean = false;
    private var leftArrow:Boolean = false;
    private var upArrow:Boolean = false;

    // ship velocity
    private var shipMoveX:Number;
    private var shipMoveY:Number;

    // timers
    private var delayTimer:Timer;
    private var shieldTimer:Timer;

    // game mode
    private var gameMode:String;
    private var shieldOn:Boolean;

    // ships and shields
    private var shipsLeft:uint;
    private var shieldsLeft:uint;
    private var shipIcons:Array;
    private var shieldIcons:Array;
    private var scoreDisplay:TextField;

    // score and level
    private var gameScore1:Number;
    private var gameLevel:uint;

    // sprites
    private var gameObjects:Sprite;
    private var scoreObjects:Sprite;


    // start the game
    public function startSpaceRocks_v008() {
        // set up sprites
        gameObjects = new Sprite();
        addChild(gameObjects);
        scoreObjects = new Sprite();
        addChild(scoreObjects);

        // reset score objects
        gameLevel = 1;
        shipsLeft = startingShips;
        gameScore1 = 0;
        createShipIcons();
        createScoreDisplay();

        // set up listeners
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveGameObjects);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownFunction);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpFunction);

        // start 
        gameMode = "delay";
        shieldOn = false;
        missiles = new Array();
        nextRockWave(null);
        newShip(null);
    }


    // SCORE OBJECTS
        // draw number of ships left
    public function createShipIcons() {
        shipIcons = new Array();
        for(var i:uint=0;i<shipsLeft;i++) {
            var newShip:ShipIcon = new ShipIcon();
            newShip.x = 460+i*30;
            newShip.y = 328;
            scoreObjects.addChild(newShip);
            shipIcons.push(newShip);
        }
    }

    // draw number of shields left
    public function createShieldIcons() {
        shieldIcons = new Array();
        for(var i:uint=0;i<shieldsLeft;i++) {
            var newShield:ShieldIcon = new ShieldIcon();
            newShield.x = 520-i*30;
            newShield.y = 210;
            scoreObjects.addChild(newShield);
            shieldIcons.push(newShield);
        }
    }


    // put the numerical score at the upper right
        public function createScoreDisplay() {
        scoreDisplay = new TextField();
        scoreDisplay.x = 460;
        scoreDisplay.y = 68;
        scoreDisplay.width = 40;
        scoreDisplay.selectable = false;
        var scoreDisplayFormat = new TextFormat();
        scoreDisplayFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;
        scoreDisplayFormat.font = "Arial";
        scoreDisplayFormat.align = "right";
        scoreDisplayFormat.size = 15;
        scoreDisplay.defaultTextFormat = scoreDisplayFormat;
        scoreObjects.addChild(scoreDisplay);
        updateScore();
    }


    // new score to show
    public function updateScore() {
        scoreDisplay.text = String(gameScore1);
    }

    // remove a ship icon
    public function removeShipIcon() {
        scoreObjects.removeChild(shipIcons.pop());
    }

    // remove a shield icon
    public function removeShieldIcon() {
        scoreObjects.removeChild(shieldIcons.pop());
    }

    // remove the rest of the ship icons
    public function removeAllShipIcons() {
        while (shipIcons.length > 0) {
            removeShipIcon();
        }
    }

    // remove the rest of the shield icons
    public function removeAllShieldIcons() {
        while (shieldIcons.length > 0) {
            removeShieldIcon();
        }
    }


    // SHIP CREATION AND MOVEMENT

    // create a new ship
    public function newShip(event:TimerEvent) {
        // if ship exists, remove it
        if (ship != null) {
            gameObjects.removeChild(ship);
            ship = null;
        }

        // no more ships
        if (shipsLeft < 1) {
            endGame();
            return;
        }

        //upper scrore reached
        if (gameScore1 >= 50) {
            trace("high")
            endGame();
            return;
        }


        // create, position, and add new ship
        ship = new Ship();
        ship.gotoAndStop(1);
        ship.x = 400;
        ship.y = 350;
        ship.rotation = -180;
        ship.shield.visible = false;
        gameObjects.addChild(ship);


        // set up ship properties
        shipMoveX = 0.0;
        shipMoveY = 0.0;
        gameMode = "play";

        // set up shields
        shieldsLeft = 3;
        createShieldIcons();

        // all lives but the first start with a free shield
        if (shipsLeft != startingShips) {
            startShield(true);
        }
    }

        // register key presses
public function keyDownFunction(event:KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
            leftArrow = true;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            rightArrow = true;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 32) { // space
            newMissile();
    } else if (event.keyCode == 37) { //  left arrow
            startShield(false);
    }
}

// register key ups
public function keyUpFunction(event:KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        leftArrow = false;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        rightArrow = false;
    }
}


    // animate ship
    public function moveShip(timeDiff:uint) {

        // rotate and thrust
                // rotate and thrust
    if (leftArrow) {
        ship.y -= 2;
    } else if (rightArrow) {
        ship.y+= 2;
        }


        // move
        ship.x += shipMoveX;
        ship.y += shipMoveY;

        // wrap around screen
        if (ship.y < 65) ship.y = 65;
        if (ship.y > 380) ship.y = 380;

    }

    // remove ship
    public function shipHit() {
        gameMode = "delay";
        ship.gotoAndPlay("explode");
        removeAllShieldIcons();
        delayTimer = new Timer(1000,1);
        delayTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,newShip);
        delayTimer.start();
        removeShipIcon();
        shipsLeft--;
    }

    // turn on shield for 3 seconds
    public function startShield(freeShield:Boolean) {
        if (shieldsLeft < 1) return; // no shields left
        if (shieldOn) return; // shield already on

        // turn on shield and set timer to turn off
        ship.shield.visible = true;
        shieldTimer = new Timer(3000,1);
        shieldTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,endShield);
        shieldTimer.start();

        // update shields remaining
        if (!freeShield) {
            removeShieldIcon();
            shieldsLeft--;
        }
        shieldOn = true;
    }

    // turn off shield
    public function endShield(event:TimerEvent) {
        ship.shield.visible = false;
        shieldOn = false;
    }
```

// ROCKS

```
    // create a single rock of a specific size
    public function newRock(x,y:int, rockType:String) {

        // create appropriate new class
        var newRock:MovieClip;
        var rockRadius:Number;
        if (rockType == "Big") {
            newRock = new Rock_Big();
            rockRadius = 35;
        } else if (rockType == "Medium") {
            newRock = new Rock_Medium();
            rockRadius = 30;
        } else if (rockType == "Small") {
            newRock = new Rock_Small();
            rockRadius = 25;
        }


        // choose a random look
        newRock.gotoAndStop(Math.ceil(Math.random()*3));

        // set start position
        newRock.x = Math.random()*0;
        newRock.y = Math.random()*280+80;


        // set random movement and rotation
        var dx:Number = Math.random()*3;  
        var dy:Number = Math.random()*2;



        // add to stage and to rocks list
        gameObjects.addChild(newRock);
        rocks.push({rock:newRock, dx:dx, dy:dy, rockType:rockType, rockRadius: rockRadius});
    }

    // create four rocks
    public function nextRockWave(event:TimerEvent) {
        rocks = new Array();
        newRock(100,1,"Big");
        newRock(200,1,"Big");
        newRock(450,1,"Big");
        newRock(350,1,"Big");
        gameMode = "play";
     }

    // animate all rocks
    public function moveRocks(timeDiff:uint) {
        for(var i:int=rocks.length-1;i>=0;i--) {

            // move the rocks
            var rockSpeed:Number = rockSpeedStart + rockSpeedIncrease*gameLevel;
            rocks[i].rock.x += rocks[i].dx*timeDiff*rockSpeed;
            rocks[i].rock.y += 0



            // wrap rocks
    if ((rocks[i].rock.x) > 400){
        deleteRocks(i);
            }
    else if ((rocks[i].rock.y) > 401){
            deleteRocks(i);
                }



        }
    }



    public function rockHit(rockNum:uint) {
        // create two smaller rocks
        if (rocks[rockNum].rockType == "Big") {
            newRock(rocks[rockNum].rock.x,rocks[rockNum].rock.y,"Medium");
            newRock(rocks[rockNum].rock.x,rocks[rockNum].rock.y,"Medium");
        } else if (rocks[rockNum].rockType == "Medium") {
            newRock(rocks[rockNum].rock.x,rocks[rockNum].rock.y,"Small");
            newRock(rocks[rockNum].rock.x,rocks[rockNum].rock.y,"Small");
        }

    // remove original rock
    rocks[rockNum].rock.gotoAndPlay("bang");
    //gameObjects.removeChild(rocks[rockNum].rock);
    rocks.splice(rockNum,1);
    }

public function deleteRocks(rockNum:uint) {
    //remove rock from game
    gameObjects.removeChild(rocks[rockNum].rock);
    rocks.splice(rockNum,1);

}



    // MISSILES

    // create a new Missile
    public function newMissile() {
        // create
        var newMissile:Missile = new Missile();

        // set direction
        newMissile.dx = Math.cos(Math.PI*ship.rotation/180);
        newMissile.dy = Math.sin(Math.PI*ship.rotation/180);

        // placement
        newMissile.x = ship.x + newMissile.dx*shipRadius;
        newMissile.y = ship.y + newMissile.dy*shipRadius;

        // add to stage and array
        gameObjects.addChild(newMissile);
        missiles.push(newMissile);
    }

    // animate missiles
    public function moveMissiles(timeDiff:uint) {
        for(var i:int=missiles.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            // move
            missiles[i].x += missiles[i].dx*missileSpeed*timeDiff;
            missiles[i].y += missiles[i].dy*missileSpeed*timeDiff;
            // moved off screen
            if ((missiles[i].x < 0) || (missiles[i].x > 550) || (missiles[i].y < 0) || (missiles[i].y > 400)) {
                gameObjects.removeChild(missiles[i]);
                delete missiles[i];
                missiles.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
    }

    // remove a missile
    public function missileHit(missileNum:uint) {
        gameObjects.removeChild(missiles[missileNum]);
        missiles.splice(missileNum,1);
    }

    // GAME INTERACTION AND CONTROL

    public function moveGameObjects(event:Event) {
        // get timer difference and animate
        var timePassed:uint = getTimer() - lastTime;
        lastTime += timePassed;
        moveRocks(timePassed);
        if (gameMode != "delay") {
            moveShip(timePassed);
        }
        moveMissiles(timePassed);
        checkCollisions();
    }

    // look for missiles colliding with rocks
    public function checkCollisions() {
        // loop through rocks
        rockloop: for(var j:int=rocks.length-1;j>=0;j--) {
            // loop through missiles
            missileloop: for(var i:int=missiles.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
                // collision detection 
                if (Point.distance(new Point(rocks[j].rock.x,rocks[j].rock.y),
                        new Point(missiles[i].x,missiles[i].y))
                            < rocks[j].rockRadius) {

                    // remove rock and missile
                    rockHit(j);
                    missileHit(i);

                    // add score
                    gameScore1 += 10;
                    updateScore();

                    // break out of this loop and continue next one
                    continue rockloop;
                }
            }

            // check for rock hitting ship
            if (gameMode == "play") {
                if (shieldOn == false) { // only if shield is off
                    if (Point.distance(new Point(rocks[j].rock.x,rocks[j].rock.y),
                            new Point(ship.x,ship.y))
                                < rocks[j].rockRadius+shipRadius) {

                        // remove ship and rock
                        shipHit();
                        rockHit(j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (gameScore1 >= 50) {
            shipsLeft = 0;
        if (shipsLeft < 1) {
            endGame();
            return;
        }

        }


        // all out of rocks, change game mode and trigger more
        if ((rocks.length == 0) && (gameMode == "play")) {
            gameMode = "betweenlevels";
            gameLevel++; // advance a level
            delayTimer = new Timer(2000,1);
            delayTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,nextRockWave);
            delayTimer.start();
        }
    }

    public function endGame() {
        // remove all objects and listeners
        removeChild(gameObjects);
        removeChild(scoreObjects);
        gameObjects = null;
        scoreObjects = null;
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveGameObjects);
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownFunction);
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpFunction);

        gotoAndStop("gameover");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Try to debug your code to get the exact lines of your errors and then correct them ... if you still have problems, you can post just the code where the error is fired ...

Comment: BTW, your 1st error is here : `delayTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,newShip(null));`, it should be : `delayTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,newShip);`, your 2nd error, I think it's here : `ship.shield.visible = true;`, verify that `ship` and `ship.shield` are not `null`, your 3rd one, I think it's about some `rocks[i]` ... debug your code to be sure ...

Comment: ... Also, try to avoid using the same name for many of your properties and methods like `newShip`, `newRock`, that makes your code more unclear and more unreadable ...

Comment: OK i've updated the script.. I think i'm not updating the code right for when I try to make then game stop when the score hits 50... there's something i'm missing to making the game restart properly...                                                        if (gameScore1 >= 50) {
            shipsLeft = 0;
        if (shipsLeft < 1) {
            endGame();
            return;
        }